# how to pass dynamic values in jqgrid Add Form

Tags: jqgrid

Below is my grid ..

[image: My Grid]
the Column TestType has a list of values (say test1, test2..test10 ) .
how can i generate Add form like this.
[image: Add]

Can any one throw some light on this?
many thanks..

[image]

[image]

**UPDATED:** 
**========**

this is how my add form should look like
[image]

Comment: any suggestion or idea will be highly appreciable

Comment: Will u please elaborate ur question like whether u want *TestType* column as dropdown or textbox, then what about other columns such as *PiecesTested*, *Result*, *Comments* ? Then only it will be easy for others to help u..

Comment: You are saying your edit form itself is a grid again?

Comment: your question is not clear as @Prakash said...

Comment: @Prakash sry for the delay.. the Column Pieces tested just a numeric text box (holds numbers). Result is a Drop down with values ('Pass','Fail'). Comments holds just plain texts.

Comment: @vissu No. My issue here is i can create an addform with individual testtype say test1 save the form. then click add button again select test2 save etc.  posted image above. i am trying to incorporate all test in a single form.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your add form should be in tabular format.  is it correct?

Comment: @vissu yes. i need all the test types to be placed when i click an add form

Comment: In that case you can create a custom form with tabular form and open it on Edit.  I would suggest to create an external add button for this.  On save save in database by using looping.  After saving reload grid, it will load the values...

Comment: @vissu i didn't get you. can you provide an example for this??

Comment: I will write as answer see there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I Understand from your above comments, Your add form need to be in Tabular format.

**A.** Easy way is Grid inline edit.  But I think it is not suitable for you.  If so,

**B.** Do the following:

1. Instead of grid's default add button use external add button.  On clicking that button open a custom form in tabular form with Save option.
2. Onclick of save button just read all fields data from the tabular form.  Here you have some small problem.
3. You may have to iterate the rows in the table to insert into the Database (This is Based on your database design).
4. On success of AJAX you just reload the Grid by using `$('#yourGrid').trigger("reloadGrid");`

This is a design idea only.  Unfortunately I do not have any example for you :(

Let me know if you need more details.

**Edit:**
**External add button:**
[image]

**Resulted add form:**
[image]

Comment: what you mean by tabular form in jqGrid?

Comment: Your form, instead of regular form your form should be in table format.  I will attach a new image now.

Comment: I am saying the same what you updated and put an image at the last.

Answer (score 0):

Do you create a jqgrid in your form?

You are have create a jqgrid like this:

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    url:'server.php?q=2',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90},
        {name:'name',index:'name asc, invdate', width:100},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right"},      
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"},       
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"JSON Example"
});
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

Where `colNames` its a caption, `colModel` contain a name and format you grid, and exists a tag `PostData` contain a arguments for populate your grid, its return a format JSON or Xml.

Do you see more in a [Wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs) and [Demos](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

You're Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**One solution** could be to go 'out of band' with jqgrid. you could add an '**onSelectRow**' attribute to your jqGrid javascript-object. Allowing it to load up some other content, say for instance in a dialog. this would look like this.

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
            url:'/path/to/jqgrid/data/',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames:['TestID','ArticleID', 'Color', 'TestType', 'Places Tested', 'Results', 'comments'],
            colModel :[ 
                        {name:'testid', index:'testid', width:35, align:'center', sortable:true}, 
                        {name:'artileid',   index:'articleid',   width:50, align:'left',   sortable:false}, 
                        {name:'color',   index:'color',   width:80, align:'left',   sortable:true}, 
                        {name:'testtype', index:'testtype', width:40, align:'right',  sortable:true}, 
                        {name:'placestested', index:'placestested', width:50, align:'center', sortable:false}, 
                        {name:'results',    index:'results',    width:50, align:'center', sortable:false}, 
                        {name:'comments',   index:'commente',   width:35, align:'center', sortable:false}
                        ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum:15,
            rowList:[15,30,60,120],
            sortname: 'testid',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            emptyrecords: "No Tests in system",
            height: "100%",
            autowidth: true,
            caption: 'Test Details',
            onSelectRow: function(id, status, event){ 
                console.log("jqGrid.onSelectRow called");
                    alert('TODO: add dialog');
                var url = "/new/dialog/server/data/' + id + "/"
                console.log(url);
                window.openDialog( url, id );
                $('tr[id=' + id + ']').removeClass('ui-state-highlight'); // no annoying white row.
            },
            loadComplete: function() {
                   console.log('jqGrid.loadcomplete');
            }
        }); // end jqGrid stanza
```

**Not Quite Finished:**
Now you need to do 3 things

1. Build the server response: that will respond to the jqgrid url request. '**/path/to/jqgrid/data/**'
2. you will need to write your javascript '**openDialog(url, id)**' function. This should be a wrapper function to a [jquery-ui dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).
3. you will need to build another server response: that will respond to the openDialog url request.

**Note**: I recommend since you are using jqGrid, you would be using a jquery-ui dialog.

**Finally**: 'just to be sure' the response that you are going to need from # 1 will look something like this.

```
    {
       "total": 1, 
       "records": 2,
       "rows": [
          {
              "cell": [ 1, 398, "red", "unit", "lab", "failed", "failed post progression bla" ],
              "id": 2
          },
          {
              "cell": [ 2,399, "green", "unit", "lab", "passed", "past post progression bla" ],
              "id": 1
          }
       ],
       "page": 1
    }
```